# Split a string using a beginning and end delimeter

Tags: java, string, parsing

I am working on a personal notifying application for when I stream.

Right now, I can read a URL, and save it as a .txt file.

Now, I'm trying to 'clean' that file.

For example, I would like to take this:

```
<tr>
    <tdclass="date">April11,2015,1:48p.m.</td>
    <tdclass="donor-name">Mr.Bob</td>
    <tdclass="charity-name">Whatever</td>
    <tdclass="amount">$15.00</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <tdclass="date">April11,2015,2:31p.m.</td>
    <tdclass="donor-name"> 
    // etc etc etc
```

And delete everything, while creating tokens like this:

Donor-name: Mr.Bob

Amount: $15.00

```
String toParse = readFile(fileName);
    toParse = toParse.replace("\n","").replace("\r","");
    toParse = toParse.replaceAll("  ", "");
    String donorPattern = "donor-name\\\">([\\w\\s\\.]*)<";
    String amountPattern = "amount\\\">([\\d\\s\\.\\$]*)<";
```

Comment: Is the contents of the text file one long string as you've shown in your example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are your parsing an HTML page? If the answer is yes maybe your best choice will be an HTML parser like JSoup: http://jsoup.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use Regex. For this case in particular, the regex to capture the groups "donor-name" and "amount" classes are:

Regex to capture the content of "donor-name":

```
donor-name\">([\w\s\.]*)<
```

Regex to captures the content of "amount":

```
amount\">([\d\s\.\$]*)<
```

They are just examples of many possible ways to use Regex and I **highly** recommend you to improve the second one to match only numbers.

For more information about Regex in java:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Hope that helps :)